# How to change the title of fragment when press back?

Tags: android, fragment, onbackpressed

I have 3 fragments, Home, Menu and orders they can be loaded by `bottomnavigtioview` items and the title shown by it as well
once navigate from Home to Orders then if you want to go back to Home From Orders the title still "Orders"

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        Fragment fragment;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_home));
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_menu:
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_title_menu));
                fragment = new ProductFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_orders:
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_orders));
                fragment = new OrdersFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // load fragment
   FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
       transaction.addToBackStack(null);
       transaction.commit();
}
```

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

     navigation =  findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);


    // attaching bottom sheet behaviour - hide / show on scroll
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) navigation.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setBehavior(new BottomNavigationBehavior());

    toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_home));
    Fragment f = HomeFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, f)
            .commit();
}`
```

I have Also Tried this but its not working

`

fragmentmanger.addOnBackStackChangedListener ->  public void onBackStackChanged() {

```
        }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me when calling it in `onResume` like this in each fragment:

`if(getActivity()!=null) { 
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle
(context.getResources().getString(R.string.YOUR_TITLE));`

this is the function `setActionBarTitle` in `MainActivity`

`public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
    }`

Comment: onResume() is not called for a fragment when its visible again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `toolbar.setTitle` in your `onNavigationItemSelected` method, move it to `onCreateView` of each fragment. When you navigate back to a Fragment, `onCreateView` is executed again.

Comment: i got nullpointerexception  'void android.app.ActionBar.setTitle(int)' on a null object reference
        at fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:112)